# stopPropagation not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of images, list contains a JPG image, on mouseover image is replaced with a GIF animation, and some text is displayed above image.

Issue is that text is firing mouseover / mouseout events. I tried to add stopPropagation() function, but its now working.

What else can be done, or am i doing something wrong?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alokjain_lucky/8f2gqua4/

HTML Code:

```
<ul class="images-list">
  <li data-gif="https://res.cloudinary.com/hu0zdcb0k/image/upload/fl_lossy,q_25/rbgo5mkmu0dldrtobrwg.gif" data-jpg="https://res.cloudinary.com/hu0zdcb0k/image/upload/w_180,h_180,q_55,c_fill,g_face,e_improve/vt5yhnzexh3vqa89hbtz.jpg">
<a href="https://www.picnic.lol/qrVy4yA">
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hu0zdcb0k/image/upload/w_180,h_180,q_55,c_fill,g_face,e_improve/vt5yhnzexh3vqa89hbtz.jpg" alt="" width="167" height="168">
</a>
<span class="image_caption">Some text here</span>
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.images-list li').on('mouseover', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var self = $(this);

    self.find('.image_caption').stop().fadeIn('slow');
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = $(this).data('gif');
    image.onload = function() {
        self.find('img').attr('src', image.src);
    }
    image.onerror = function() {
        console.error("Cannot load image");
    }
  })

  $('.images-list li').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', $(this).data('jpg'));
    $(this).find('.image_caption').stop().fadeOut('slow');
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stopPropagation isn't going to help because it only stops the same event from propagating to other elements. Your case is firing a separate time. You need to use mouseenter instead of mouseover.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.images-list li').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    var self = $(this);

    self.find('.image_caption').stop().fadeIn('slow');
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = $(this).data('gif');
    image.onload = function() {
        self.find('img').attr('src', image.src);
    }
    image.onerror = function() {
        console.error("Cannot load image");
    }
  })

  $('.images-list li').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', $(this).data('jpg'));
    $(this).find('.image_caption').stop().fadeOut('slow');
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mouseenter` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter)) instead of `mouseover` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover)).